# how to increase the resolution of logitech c920 to detect aruco markers more stably

Tags: ros, camera, resolution, video, usb-cam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using logitech c920(about 12ft above ground) to detect an aruco marker using the aruco_ros library. The resolution is set to 640x480 but at this resolution the aruco marker is not being detected if anything slightly comes in front of the marker. I wanted to see if i increase the resolution to 720p the aruco marker detection becomes more stable.

I tried to change it in the (edit:usb_cam-stream)launch file but that did not help. It gives this error - "No jpeg data found in image. Error while decoding frame."

I tried to change the pixel format to yuyv from mjpeg but it was giving some other error. "VIDIOC_DQBUF error 19, No such device"

I also tried to change the resolution using v4l2-ctl but there wasn't an option to change it.

Anyone know of a different way to increase the resolution or know of a different aruco library that does more stable detection? Also is there a camera that does aruco detection better that is not too expensive? The goal is to detect the markers well about 10-15ft away and also not completely lose the marker when there is a small obstacle(eg: 3in diameter ball).

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275292/how-to-increase-the-resolution-of-logitech-c920-to-detect-aruco-markers-more-stably/) by [eric_cartman](https://answers.ros.org/users/31773/eric_cartman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2017-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A resolution and image format that works in an application like guvcview probably also works in usb_cam (maybe not all pixel types)- it is very quick and easy to experiment there then bring the changes to the parameters to usb_cam.

Also v4l2-ctl will list valid resolution and format combinations:

```
v4l2-ctl --device=0 --list-formats-ext
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0